# Boolean Modifier cutting the wrong part

Tags: modeling

So, I have been trying to make a Jett's knife model in Blender. Everything was fine until I tried to cut a hole in the knife. Since I have only been using Blender for like 5-6 days only, I searched for some ways to do that. I found that I needed to use a Boolean Modifier, so I did. I selected the knife, and the cube that I edited into the shape of the blade. But, when I selected the cube in the "Object" part of the modifier, it removed the blade instead. I don't know why this happens, maybe I did something wrong. I tried to follow other things on the Internet but it still failed. How can I fix this?

I was expecting the circled part to be cut out. But it cut the outside instead.[image]

https://youtu.be/qV_g0ASsFHo
Here is what I did

Comment: Maybe try Solver > Fast instead of Exact in the Boolean modifier. If it still doesn't work, maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Do you know where the solver is? I can't seem to find it
I uploaded the file, you can give it a check.

Comment: in the modifier > Solver > choose Fast, not Exact. About the file: you need to share the link  ;)

Comment: It turns out that you have bad geometry in your 'cutter' cube.  Fixing that and applying the boolean to both objects fixes it.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a chance to look at the actual blend file, and I found geometry problems.  Let me show you how I found and fixed one.

I took your Cube cutter into edit mode in a local window.  (If you have a number pad on your keyboard the / character on the pad toggles that mode.)

Then I used the select menu to select interior faces

[image: selecting interior faces]

Turns out you've got one:

[image: interior face on cutter]

That's going to confuse the boolean operator, so delete it.  Use the X key and select "Faces".

It still doesn't work because you have **two** objects you need to apply the Boolean to, "Blade" and "Middle Knifu"; so I added the boolean to each.

[image: and it worked]

and it worked.

ASIDE: You have a lot of bad geometry in both the blade and Middle Knifu.  In addition to interior faces you have duplicated vertices and you have interior edges.

ORIGINAL ANSWER STARTS HERE:

Be sure that you apply the Boolean modifier to the cube that represents the blade and **not** the object you are using to 'cut' the hole.  Here's a crude example:

[image: "blade" with hole]

What you don't see in the example is the cylinder I used as the 'cutter' object.  If you look at my scene collection you'll see why:

[image: scene collection showing cylinder is not visible.]

When you select the blade and go to the modifiers panel, the Boolean modifier should look like this:

[image: boolean modifier to make hole]

Notice that the modifier is applied to the blade and that the "Object" in the modifier is the cylinder.

Below the Object there's a 'Solver' box.  I have it set to Fast.

A common rookie mistake is to apply the modifer but leave the cylinder visible.  If you do this it looks like nothing happened:

[image: Cylinder is visible]

There are a couple of ways to solve this.  For the example I simply made the Cylinder invisible:

[image: Cylinder invisible in 3D view space]

If you do it this way, the cylinder will still show up in renders.  You have to also make it invisible to the camera:

[image: cylinder invisible to camera]

Alternatively, if you are going to use a lot of Booleans a better technique is to move the cylinder to a new collection, usually called 'cutters':

Select the cylinder and type M.  this will bring up a menu:

[image: move menu]

Since you don't already have a collection, select "new collection" and give the collection a name.

[image: moving to new collection called 'cutters']

Now all you have to do is uncheck the box for the cutters and the cylinder won't show up in the 3D view or on a render:

[image: cutters collection disabled]

Comment: Soo, I did what you said. I selected my blade, added the Boolean Modifier, choose the "cutter" cube, chose Fast, and I hid the "cutter". But..., It's still not working. Am I doing anything wrong again.

Here's the file of the knifu: https://pasteall.org/blend/ec34ba87127b43998ca32c8b33412ab5

Here's the video of what i did:
https://youtu.be/f_KNWTVbNMs

Comment: I can't download your blend file because pasteall is giving me a 'file not found', but looking at your video it looks like your cutter cube isn't big enough to go all the way through the knife body, and that's confusing the boolean.  Otherwise you've done the right thing.  Can you try again on the paste?

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/7c0efd330c194be98e746ff18a3227c4

Comment: Got that version, and you've got bad geometry that is causing the boolean operator to be confused.  I'll write an answer shortly.

Comment: All right. Thx btw

Comment: Another question, sorry mate.
https://prnt.sc/12czh1v
how do i fix this?
is it because of the geometry?
This happened after I added the boolean

Comment: Yes, it is probably because of the geometry.  When you use a 3d application you can create geometry that can't exist in the real world.  Sometimes this doesn't matter. For instance you have two objects, the knife blade and knife middle, that occupy the same space.  But when you do it in a single object, it can mess up modifiers.  Ask another question and I'll try to show you -- there's not enough room in a comment for an answer.

Comment: Alright. but it's ok. I'll try to make another one. Thx btw